# Does spoiler text show up on the Questions page?

Tags: support, spoilers

> This is spoiler text at the top of the post.

I'm testing to see if it shows up on the Questions page.

<strike>It appears that it does, so follow up question:</strike>

Do we just need to be careful about putting spoiler text at the top of a post, or can it be fixed so that it doesn't get displayed as normal text?

Comment: Should be fixed. It spoiled something for me (a little)

Comment: Note that this isn't the case any more: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/461/spoilered-text-is-visible-on-the-questions-page

Comment: Thanks @TonyMeyer.  I've updated my answer to note that this is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Yes, it does.</strike> [Not anymore](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/how-can-i-track-down-the-meta-question-that-fixed-the-spoiler-behavior).

[image: Spoiler-Fixed]

Here's the old view of the same question with the spoiler text showing.

[image: spoiler text appears]

Answer (score 0):

I think just excluding it from the text on the front page would work. Probably we have to ask this on meta.stackexchange.com rather than here, though? (if it gets rejected, then we have the inferior "be careful how you write" option).