# Spoilered text is visible on the Questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers, markdown

If the text of a question has spoiler text near the beginning, this spoiler text might appear on the `/questions` page ([example question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/does-spoiler-text-show-up-on-the-questions-page); [question search result illustrating the issue](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers+support)). It'd be nice if the site realized it's not cool to spoil people.

Comment: This [has been noticed before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/333/does-spoiler-text-show-up-on-the-questions-page), though it wasn't framed as a bug report then. It's not clear to me what the behavior should be, though: what about people who want to see all the text on the questions page?

Comment: They can't reliably see all of a question's text on the Questions page anyway, so they shouldn't have that expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that spoiler questions have a bit (300 chars+) of lead-in text.

We won't be making any special considerations for this, and I think responsible use of spoilers requires users to "do the right thing" anyway.

Comment: Why not? Is there _any_ good reason to show spoiler text in the summary?

Comment: @Tim: I highly doubt there's a condition in the summary-generation code that explicitly tests for spoilers *and then includes them.* In fact, I doubt there's any real Markdown processing done for generating summaries *period* - it's probably just stripped and truncated. Which means implementing this requires adding a significant amount of complexity to what is now a *very fast, simple system*, purely to support users who just can't be bothered to write a question that doesn't start off with a spoiler. So: can you make a compelling argument for why questions *should* lead with a spoiler?

Comment: @Shog9: It's natural in [some questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/did-scout-know-all-along). That it is be hard to implement would be a better reason (although I don't think it is).

Comment: @Tim: regardless of how trivial or hard it is to implement, you've gotta assume when suggesting a feature that it starts off with a negative priority and do your utmost to justify the cost - whatever that might be - of its implementation by clearly laying out the potential benefit to be realized.

Answer (score 2):

This bug report was initially declined but is now [resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89552/can-we-please-remove-spoilered-text-from-the-summary).

> This has been mostly completed and is now active - now, the question summaries on the Questions pages, as well as the summary tooltip on the Front Page will hide any spoiler text that is in the first 200 characters.
>
> It's only mostly completed as RSS Feeds and search results do not cover up spoiler text.