# Add support for the spoiler markup to chat

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, chat

When question links are posted in chat (manually or by the automatic system) they get auto-formatted so that the question title and some of the text is displayed.

It would be convenient if the spoiler markup worked in chat, so that chat didn't get unexpected spoilers (especially in the case where the questions are being auto-posted, since a spoiler can turn up in chat with no warning at all).

This is seemingly worse than the text in the question page because more of the text is included, so even if the question text is padded enough to avoid showing the in the question page, it may still spoil in chat.  In addition, it's not possible (except for mods?) to edit these postings once they have been made, so once the spoiler is in chat, it's there until enough new messages scroll it off.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big proponent of not getting spoiled on stories I haven't experienced yet.  I think the chat blurb should properly parse spoiler markdown, and I really wish the previous [attempts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/461/1027) to get this issue addressed for the Questions page had gone otherwise.

What other SE sites use spoilers nearly as much as we do?  Based on the reaction from the developers on previous spoiler-centric bugs/feature-requests, I seriously doubt they'll take this request currently.  If there was a more populous SE community that uses spoilers frequently, I'd suggest we get this question migrated to their meta site, so it'll get enough votes for the developers to care.

Comment: I think [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) uses spoilers, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this feature request. On the chat, anyone can post anything at any time, and I would oppose a “no spoiler” policy for non-automated messages. Therefore hiding spoilers in automated messages seems futile.